# Sparkline based on Expression using custom code

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report which is reporting sales grouped by Month. One of the columns in this report is a calculated fields which takes 2 values and passes them to a custom code routine that is defined for this report. The textbox that is populated with the following code:

```vb
=Code.DivideBy(ReportItems!textbox21.Value, ReportItems!EarnedIncome1.Value)
```

All this Custom Code does is to divide the First Parameter by the Second Parameter (in this case whatever is in textbox21/EarnedIncome). The response is them shown on the screen as a percentage.

Below is an example of the report:

[1 http://www.propelpos.com/images/screenshot002.jpg](http://www.propelpos.com/images/screenshot002.jpg)

This worked great. What we are trying to do now is to graphy the % that is in the BDX Loss ratio column which is figured out by the formula above (dividing Losses by Earned Premium)

When I try to copy the expression in the chart data and set the Category Groups to PeriodYearMonth (same as all the others), then I get a straight line.

I have no idea where to go next.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing the calculation in your query and then using that computed column in SSRS. If you need help figuring out how to do that, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Neil. You can also Add the Calculated field in you data set properties. Take a look at the following screen. You can set the expression to calculate the data for your line chart.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This should work as well. However, I really try to not do any kinds of these calculations in SSRS as I have found it to degrade performance.

Comment: Thanks @Neil. I agree with your point. It is just the workaround.